# Read substring from char array

Tags: arrays, arduino, char, substring

I'm trying to read a substring of a char array in arduino.

I have my char array variable initialized like this

```
char msg[115] = "Data received: HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Sat, 04 Mar 2017 17:43:10 GMT Content-Length: 13 {line:\"Azul\"}";
```

But I can't figure out how can I get the substring `{line:\"Azul\"}` or more idealy, get just the `Azul` result from the " index.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Quick&Dirty: `char* realMessage = strstr(msg, "Content-Length") + strlen("Content-Length: ") + 3;`. Cleaner: How about getting the a pointer to `Content-Length:` (`char* szContentLen = strstr(msg, "Content-Length:");`, then parse the next few chars as an `int` with `atoi()` or `strtol()`, and then retrieve the rest of the string with the parsed out length, with out-of-bounds checks ofcouse. The payload can then be parsed by using a proper JSON parser (jsmn for example)

Comment: Hello @MaximilianGerhardt

I'm trying to parse the next chars as an int with atoi() or strtol() but I'm unable to. I just want to catch the text in between the curly brackets. So how can I delimit till the next } brack? 
Can you help me out?

Comment: Show us your code then. As I said, parsing the HTTP response cleanly is the way to go. First the headers (up to `\r\n\r\n`), from the headers the `Content-Length`, from that the response body. Another quick&dirty way would be (if it's just really the braces you're interested in): `char* response = strstr(msg, "{");` . I.e. just get a pointer to the place at which you find the first `{`. You'd then ideally parse that string with a proper JSON parser (e.g. jsmn in C.)